# ¿Como convertir array de hexadecimales a un único valor decimal con Python?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente array con hexadecimales:

`array = ['0xA7', '0xF3', '0x8', '0x0']`

No son valores string los que están dentro del array, son el resultados de hacer:

`hex(167)= 0xA7`

`hex(243)= 0xF3`

`...`

Como se pueden concatenar los valores del array de la siguiente forma:

`0008F3A7`

De forma tal que se pueda calcular el valor decimal de esa concatenación con:

`int('0008F3A7',16) = 586663`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La salida de `hex` es una cadena con la representación en hexadecimal de un entero precedida de `"0x"`. Por lo tanto como cadenas debes manipularlas:

```
 >>> "".join(byte.lstrip("0x").rjust(2, "0") for byte in reversed(array))
'0008f3a7'
```

Sería todo más simple si usaras `f"{entero:02x}"` para obtener la representación en vez de `hex()`.

```
>>> enteros = (167, 243, 8, 0)
>>> array = [f"{entero:02x}" for entero in enteros]
>>> array
['a7', 'f3', '08', '00']
>>> int("".join(reversed(array)), 16)
586663
```

Le agrego un cero a la izquierda a las representaciones de 0 a 15 porque es lo que muestras en tu ejemplo, pero ten en cuenta que este cero no es inocuo si se agrega en medio de la cadena concatenada. Tampoco tendría sentido si incluyes valores por encima de 255.

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias!